# Safari Fallback for 100vh

Tags: jquery, html, css, safari

I am having an issue with the `100vh` property not being recognized in Safari and was unable to find a solution that worked for me. Here's what I've tried:

CSS

```
  .section {
    height: calc(100% - 82px); /* Fallback for safari */
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - 82px);
    height: calc(100vh - 82px);
    height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 82px);
  }
```

HTML

```
  <section id="landing" class="section" style="background-color: red">
  </section>

  <section id="about" class="section" style="background-color: blue">
  </section>
```

This works fine in Chrome, but not at all in Safari. Is there an easy way to do this with CSS or is this simple enough with jQuery?

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/brnfrs91/)

Comment: have you tried the following: `height: -webkit-calc(100% - 82px);`

Comment: Yes, I did try that with no success and updated my answer